# 95% of visits in Hostname report are from my sites domain, not the IP addresses and host names of clients

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, users

Taking a look at the hostname report in Google Analytics more than 95% of the traffic is my sites domain. I'm wondering if this is correct or if something is misconfigured.

When I log into my website I receive an email that reports the client hostname and location. These client host names are not found at all in the Google Analytics report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hostname report in Google Analytics is about the server's hostname, it's the hostname where the GA tracking code was run, which is why you should see your own hostname.

Google Analytics does not report on the visitors's IP or hostname due to privacy policy. 
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2763052

Comment: Ok, I was hoping that would be able to see the users network name so I could filter out certain types of traffic. But it looks as if that is not possible.